# Trying to host a game server on my raspberry pi - Security concerns & Static Routing

Tags: networking, static-routes

I am attempting to host a game server (Kerbal Space Program - Lunar Multiplayer Mod)
I know from past experience I need to open a port but
On my router all I have is:
"Static Routing"

And to set up a static route, it aks for:
"Destination IP"
"Subnet Mask"
"Gateway IP"
I have no idea what I should set those to.

I might be missing the port forwarding option, but I just cant find it.
Router Specs:
Model:`844G-1`
Serial Number:`422104098269FSAN`
Number:`CXNK00ABD218`
Release:`12.2.12.2.3`

I was reading and it seems like static routing is similar to port forwarding, I just don't know how to set it up.

Edit:
The server has done automatic port forwarding, I still would like to know how to do it for future reference though.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the brand and type of your router. The wording of this feature differs between manufacturers. I've seen it called port forwarding and port triggering, but static routing is most likely not what you're looking for.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.